# Why MapReduce progress report is NOT monotonically increasing?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, report, task

I submitted a MapReduce job to Hadoop and watch the progress report on screen. The progress report should be monotonically increasing (for example 0%, 10%, 25%, 60%, 78%, 95% and 100%) for both map tasks and reduce tasks. But as a matter of fact the progress reported was not monotonically increasing:

```
14/01/21 11:05:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201401201555_0036
14/01/21 11:05:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0%  reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 11% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0%  reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 9%  reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 22% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 31% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 39% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 53% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 57% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 55% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 43% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 48% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 40% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 30% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 40% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 49% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 57% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 70% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 73% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 82% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 93% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 94% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 95% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 96% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 98% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:06:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 99% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:07:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/01/21 11:07:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 4%
14/01/21 11:07:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 8%
14/01/21 11:07:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 66%
14/01/21 11:07:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 67%
14/01/21 11:07:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 68%
14/01/21 11:07:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 69%
14/01/21 11:07:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 70%
14/01/21 11:07:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 71%
14/01/21 11:07:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 72%
14/01/21 11:07:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 73%
14/01/21 11:08:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/01/21 11:08:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201401201555_0036
```

The progress is indicated by the percentage splits already been processed among all the input splits. But why is the progress report not monotonically increasing?

Answer (score 1):

Check the logs of the tasktrackers and the jobtracker. Are there any failures in the map phase? If a machine fails to perform a task, or the master cannot reach it anymore,then the task is performed again, starting from scratch, by another machine; so the progress is not monotonically increased.

Comment: I checked the UI(http://jobtracker:50030) and found that there is no failed/killed task attempt, I supposed this means there is no failure in the map phase. Yet the progress of this job is not monotonically increased.

Comment: Do you use `conf.setProgress(float progress)` anywhere (I don't think so)? If yes, then maybe you set it to a lower value somewhere.
How many nodes do you use? One or more? Is there any Exception caught (check each tasktracker's log). Did you check the *log* of the jobtracker?

Comment: I have seen this many times. Do check the logs: should likely be errors occurring.

Comment: I have 10 nodes in my cluster with one as namenode/jobtracker and others as datanode/tasktracker. I did not use `conf.setProgress(float process)`. I checked each tasktracker's log and found: a) there is no exception caught; b) there are 2 task attempts killed; c) all the tasktrackers received *'KillJobAction'*.
Actually, the results were all correct.

Comment: This problem does not affect the results, since the job finishes succesfully. It is just a matter of re-doing things that have already been done, due to some (communication perhaps) errors. The two killed attemps, I think, do not explain the five (11%->0%, 57%->50%, 55%->43%, 48%->40%, 40%->30%) progress decreases that appear in your output. What about the output of the jobtracker's log?